# Why telegram bots with admin rights can't promote group members?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I added my bot to the group and gave him all possible rights. When I call `getChatAdministrators` api I can see that bot has `can_promote_members` right:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "user": {
                "id": _id_,
                "is_bot": true,
                "first_name": "MyBot",
                "username": "TestBot"
            },
            "status": "administrator",
            "can_be_edited": false,
            "can_manage_chat": true,
            "can_change_info": true,
            "can_delete_messages": true,
            "can_invite_users": true,
            "can_restrict_members": true,
            "can_pin_messages": true,
            "can_promote_members": true,
            "can_manage_voice_chats": true,
            "custom_title": "Admin",
            "is_anonymous": true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But when I try to promote user with `promoteChatMember`, I receive an error:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 403,
    "description": "Forbidden: RIGHT_FORBIDDEN"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an issue. I shouldn't fill fields `can_post_messages` and `can_edit_messages` in `promoteChatMember`, because they are only for [channels](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#promotechatmember).